# Can I change the web.config connection string due to a Request parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

Somethings like :

```
if(Request["connectionToUse"] + "" == "constr1")
    // use a connection string 1
else 
    // use a connection string 2
```

is it possible on .NET?

Comment: You can have several connection strings in your web.config and reference them by their name : http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx

Comment: Do you want to modify web config and update the existing connection string in there ?

Comment: yes habib.osu, that's what I want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This is probably a very bad idea, as said by Oded, but if you really want to then :

modify the webconfig based on the request parameter look at the following example:

```
string strDevConnection = @"Data Source=DEVELOPMENT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sqlDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID= ;Password= ";

string strLiveConnection = @"Data Source=PRODUCTION\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sqlDB;User id= ;password= ";

Configuration myWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
if (Request["connectionToUse"] + "" == "constr1")

{

myWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["constr1"].ConnectionString = strDevConnection; //constr1 is the name of the current connectionstring in the web.config

}

else

{

myWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["constr2"].ConnectionString = strLiveConnection;

}
 myWebConfig.Save(); //Save the changes to web config
```

Comment: This is such a bad idea, though, as the app pool will reset on the `Save`.

Comment: @Oded, yeah, but this is what he wants

Comment: @Oded says : "Any changes to the web.config will reset the application, causing all users of it to drop - the application pool restarts when the file changes.". Will your code suffer that problem?

Comment: @markzzz, oh yeah for sure, if you want to avoid app pool reset, change your approach, as in the answer by Oded

Comment: So, in your code...the application will never start : every time I open it, it do the save! So it will reset, and the application will restart... :O

Comment: @markzzz, webconfig changes will cause the application to restart, I thought you might need to do it once in your application (still can't figure out the scenario), but my answer was about modifying web config through code

Comment: Ok! But as example, if I put your code, I will never get the code. I rewrite the webconfig every time...so the application will always restart... without getting any results...

Answer (score 2):

Have two connection strings in your `web.config` and simply reference the one you want to use:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add 
      name="conn1" connectionString="..." 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
   />
   <add 
      name="conn2" connectionString="..." 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
   />
</connectionStrings>

if(Request["connectionToUse"] + "" == "constr1")
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn1"];
else 
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn2"];
```

---

Update:

I don't recommend writing to your `web.config` based on passed in parameters - not only does this look like it can cause a security issue (especially if you simply *use* the passed in parameters).

Any changes to the `web.config` will reset the application, causing all users of it to drop - the application pool restarts when the file changes.

Comment: I think he wants to modify the connection in web config

Comment: @habib.osu - Read the details of the question. I think it is clear that the OP wants to use a _different_ connection string depending on the passed in parameter.

Comment: Yes! I want to have only 1 connection string in the webconfig...and edit it due to Request param, as said by habib.osu

Comment: I have a system which take ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"]. But it can refeer to 2 different database (which are on different server). I can't edit the whole system with your code (too much deep work). That's why I want to edit it...

Comment: I don't think the problem is the security (I will set it internally, not to request param). The problem could be what you say about pool and dropping...

Comment: @markzzz - You are going to introduce more bugs and difficulty by rewriting the `web.config` file. Do you need to refer to two different databases _all the time_? If so, when you keep _rewriting_ the `web.config` you will be kicking your users off the system on _every_ rewrite. What I am suggesting is the _correct_ solution - bite the bullet and do it.